# Is there any way to get post meta from publish_post hook?

Tags: plugin-development, hooks

I want a post meta of the published post, below is the code but I didn't get it. Appreciate if anyone can help me here:

```
class BarrioBlog {
    function __construct() {
      add_action( 'publish_post', array( $this, 'on_publish_post' ), 10, 2 );
    }
    function on_publish_post($post_id, $post) {
       echo ' custom field: ' . get_field('channel', $post_id);
       exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the `save_post` hook instead? It fires multiple times, but if you use that hook and check whether `$_POST` contains any data, and only do your action when it does, you'll have access to all the postmeta.

Comment: In my case save_post hook is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so it was resolved with `do_action( 'acf/save_post', $post_id );`